# There is any quick way to, while debuging, to stop at a specific Windows Message or API?

Tags: delphi, debugging, winapi, windows-messages, conditional-breakpoint

So I want to put a Breakpoint in a specific API or Windows message. 
I don't find any easy way to do that without writing code in any Delphi version. 
Is there a way to do that similar as I can put a breakpoint in memory access?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To stop at any call to an API function, find it in the `implementation` section of *Windows.pas* (or wherever the function of interest is declared) and set a breakpoint. That takes care of functions you use with load-time dynamic linking. For run-time dynamic linking (`LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`), you'll need a different technique. The variable that gets the result of `GetProcAddress` will hold the address you want to break at, but I don't know off-hand how to set a breakpoint at that address.

Stopping on a Window message is trickier since messages can be retrieved in many places. You'll have to use conditional breakpoints instead.

To catch most posted messages, you can put a breakpoint in `TApplication.HandleMessage` on the first line after the call to `PeekMessage`. Set the condition to be `Msg.Message = x`. `HandleMessage` takes care of messages posted to the main thread's message queue for the main `Application.Run` message loop as well as the VCL's modal message loops. Other modal dialogs (such as `Windows.MessageBox`) won't use it, though.

Observing *sent* messages is harder because the OS dispatches them to their target window procedures directly. You'll have to set a breakpoint in the window procedure of every window class you're interested in. You could get most VCL window classes by putting your conditional breakpoint in `Classes.StdWndProc`.

Keep in mind that conditional breakpoints can be very slow. They work by the debugger putting an *unconditional* breakpoint there, and when the OS triggers it, the debugger takes over, checks the condition, and then resumes execution if the conditional fails. That can involve a lot of overhead, switching between the debugger and your application; programs receive *lots* of messages, so if you can find a way to avoid having the debugger interrupt your program to check *every one* of them, do it.

If this isn't feasible for whatever it is you're trying to debug, then I recommend posting a new question where you describe the problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: You can add a break point at a particular address... Go to the breakpoints window after you have run the application have broken at a break point (like at the call to `GetProcAddress`), capture the address of the procedure somehow, open the breakpoints windows, right click and choose Add > Address Breakpoint. You then put in the address. The debugger should break when it hits that address. Note: The address is obviously only valid for the one invocation of your executable.

Comment: +1. This question was motived by a new colleague that is a new Delphi user. He missed the fact that in Visual Basic he could do a kind of "track next user movement" (while debugging, debugger stop on user click, enter, etc... but not while application is "idle"). Using callstack, I never feel the need of that. But realized that I could use a BP in WindowsAPI and Messages to solve some weird bugs. As I remembered that in another advanced debugger, I could just do `BPX WM_GETTEXTA` in a console window, I've wondered if Delphi had an easier way too.

Comment: @Nat hmmm... Maybe I could use some of the new Delphi Debugger's API to automatize that task... But I'm not so familiarized with that... Would this be a good question?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go into Options | Linker and check "Debug DCUs".  by default this is not checked so the debugger doesn't step through the entire VCL when you're trying to work.

Comment: Beside this is a valid and important comment. I am not asking a way to debug the VCL. You can't comment with low reputation... That is not cool. I know... :(